What public domain declarations with fall back permissive licenses are approved by both the FSF and OSI?
I was looking into public domain declarations with fall back permissive licenses (for brevity, I am going to call this concept a "public domain license") recently. For those unaware, it is my understanding that public domain is not a concept in all jurisdictions and in some you cannot willingly place things into it. A "public domain license" is appealing because it would be maximally permissive by being in the public domain (where possible) and have a permissive license (where not).
I noticed that System Package Data Exchange (SPDX) lists Creative Commons Zero v1.0 Universal (SPDX identifier: CC0-1.0) as approved by the Free Software Foundation (FSF) but not the Open Source Initiative (OSI). This is what for me curious initially. I've since learned that the FSF only approves CC0 for "Works of Practical Use besides Software and Documentation". (Whether SPDX is wrong to list CC0 as approved by FSF is out of scope for this specific question.) If you're curious about why CC0 is not approved by the OSI you can read about it in this email thread but the gist seems to be that it in section 4 it specifically says "No [...] patent rights held by Affirmer are waived, abandoned, surrendered, licensed or otherwise affected by this document" and that this violates point 7 of the OSI's Open Source Definition (OSD) which is "Distribution of license. The rights attached to the program must apply to all to whom the program is redistributed without the need for execution of an additional license by those parties." I wondered why other permissive licenses that do not explicitly grant patent rights (of which there are many, but MIT is a specific example). The argument seems to be that while most permissive licenses do not explicitly grant patent rights it may be argued that it is implicitly granted by saying you can do anything with the software.
As far as I can tell The Unlicense is the only "public domain license" approved by both the FSF (here) and OSI (approved here and discussed here). The Unlicense may be undesirable for people due to problems discussed here on the OSI's mailing list. It's worth mentioning that The Unlicense only gained approval from the OSI as a legacy license in 2020 and that legacy licenses have different approval conditions than new licenses. The thread discussing problems is from 2012, ~2 years after the license was created.
